# In SwiftUI, iOS15, 2nd level NavigationLink, isActive is not working

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

in iOS15, it is not working:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Dest1().navigationTitle("Dest1")
            } label: {
                Text("to Destination 1")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Dest1: View {
    @State var dest2Active: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Button {
                dest2Active = false // not working!!
            } label: {Text("dismiss")} .navigationTitle("Dest2"),
            isActive: $dest2Active
        ) {Text("to Destination 2")}
    }
}
```

The `dismiss` button in `Dest2` is not working!
I remember that in iOS14, this code works well.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to make it work.
Here is the test code that works for me.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Dest1().navigationTitle("Dest1")
            } label: {
                Text("to Destination 1")
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack) // <-- here the important bit
    }
}

struct Dest1: View {
    @State var dest2Active: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Button {
                dest2Active = false // now working!!
            } label: {Text("dismiss")} .navigationTitle("Dest2"),
            isActive: $dest2Active
        ) {Text("to Destination 2")}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding `.isDetailLink(false)` to the top level `NavigationLink` seems to solve the issue. Note that this works on iPhone iOS -- for iPad, you will need to use a StackNavigationStyle as @workingdog suggests in their answer.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/isdetaillink(_:)) is not clear on *why* this works (in fact, it refers specifically to multi-column navigation), but it seems to solve a number of `NavigationLink`-related issues. See, for example: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667460

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Dest1()
                    .navigationTitle("Dest1")
            } label: {
                Text("to Destination 1")
            }.isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
}

struct Dest1: View {
    @State var dest2Active: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(isActive: $dest2Active) {
            Dest2(dest2Active: $dest2Active)
        } label: {
            Text("to Destination 2")
        }
    }
}

struct Dest2: View {
    @Binding var dest2Active : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            dest2Active = false
        } label: {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }.navigationTitle("Dest2")
    }
}
```